# $l$-adic rigidity for Milnor $K$-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, rigidity

Given a local henselian ring $A$ with the maximal ideal $m$, does the quotient map $A\mapsto A/m$ induce isomorphisms on $l$-adic Milnor $K$-theories? ($K_n^M(R)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_l$, where $l$ is an invertible prime.)